# Using Foreach-Object on a AD-Query, Comparing Pipeline Variables

Tags: powershell, foreach, active-directory

i have the following Code in Powershell:

```
   Get-ADUser -filter * -property Distinguishedname | 
                                              Where-Object {($_.Distinguishedname.split(',')[2]).trimstart("OU=") -like 'Verkauf'} | 
                                              Select-Object  @{name='User'; expression={$_.samaccountname}}, @{Name='Abteilung' ;Expression={($_.Distinguishedname.split(',')[1]).trimstart("OU=")}} | 
                                              Sort-Object Abteilung, user | 
                                              Where-Object {$_.Abteilung -eq "z"} |
                                              ForEach-Object{get-aduser -filter * -Properties mail | Where-Object {$_.samaccountname -eq $_.User}}
```

Everything works except the last line. I want to filter AD-User which are in a specific department. When I cut the last line I get the following Output(I only censored the Users):

```
User    Abteilung
----    ---------
xx      Z        
xx      Z        
xx      Z        
xx      Z        
xx      Z        
xx      Z
```

With that Array I want to compare each Username with the Userlist in our Active Directory and get their associated E-Mail. But as Result I get nothing as Output when I add the last Line.

Could it have something to do with the comparison of the 2 Pipeline-Variables from 2 different queries?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If I get it right you are filtering on one particular OU. Why don't you use the parameter `-SearchBase` instead. It should speed up your code and make easier readable. You should move your second `Where-Object` directly behind the `Get-ADUser`and you don't need a second `Get-ADUser` - you already have the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distinguished name is part of the standard output of `Get-ADUser`. You don't need to force it with the parameter `-Properties`. On the other hand "mail" is not part of the standard output.  If I got you right and you're looking for the users in a particular OU in your AD the following snippet should be enough. Of course you should specify the complete path to the OU for the parameter `-SearchBase`

```
Get-ADUser -filter * -Properties mail -SearchBase 'Pfad zur OU Verkauf' | 
    Where-Object { ($_.Distinguishedname.split(',')[1]).trimstart("OU=") -eq "z" } |
        Select-Object  @{name = 'User'; expression = { $_.samaccountname } }, @{Name = 'Abteilung' ; Expression = { ($_.Distinguishedname.split(',')[1]).trimstart("OU=") } }, Mail | 
            Sort-Object Abteilung, user
```